# Regex not accepting @ character

Tags: regex

I am working with a code not mine, and I encountered a problem where when entering an email address with the character @ it get rejected. I have little knowledge in regex, can anybody explain please?

```
Character = getWrongCharacters(field,/^$|^[a-zA-Z0-9.-\s]*$/,false);
```

Comment: There are a lot of available remade regex for mail. It is better to find one than creating it on your own.

Comment: I would be surprised if that regular expression matched anything because I'm pretty sure that minus sign is used for ranges and I don't think .-\s is a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a library or what language this is, but it seems like the "field" is the input paramenter. in this case the 'e-mail', and the second parameter is the regular expression.

Check this page out for details on the regular expression to understand it
https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

If you want to Test the expression, and you have Notepad++, do the following

> type some random text in:
>
> > name@Test.com
> >
> > named123@Test.com
> >
> > name3
>
> press ctrl + f, and switch the search mode to "Regular Expression"

You can input the expression you have in your second parameter and begin searching.

I hope this helps!!